# Squid filters some of Bugzilla HTTPs URLs

Tags: ssl, squid, https

I am trying to finetune web filtering with squid, but meeting ununderstandable behaviour (for me).

For example, if I open the following address:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

It goes fine. But if I try to open

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/data/assets/6fb171799a3557e3bc6f917d8ad18e8a.css?1461277655

it shows squid prohibited page. I don't have any bugzilla's sites in explicit list.

**UPDATE**

Another finding.

If I open URL

`https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/ru/init.faad1a` and longer it shows prohibited page. If I open `https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/ru/init.faad1` and shorter, it displays twitter 404 page, i.e. passes squid.

I can't find anything matching these difference. May be I don't know, how to check?

Prohibiting rule looks like this

```
acl adslist url_regex -i "/etc/squid/adslist.txt"
http_access deny adslist
```

while the `adslist.txt` looks like this:

```
.101com.com
.101order.com
.103092804.com
.103bees.com
.1100i.com
.123banners.com
.123found.com
.123pagerank.com
.180hits.de
```

May lines like these partially match the rule and trigger 403?

Comment: is there anything in `/etc/squid/adslist.txt` or `/etc/squid/hangers.txt` that matches your bugzilla URL?

Comment: I am not sure how to check? May be there are partial matching happen?

Comment: try something like `echo 'https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/ru/init.faad1a' | grep -E -f adslist.txt`.   based on the example URLs you provided, it may turn out to be a pattern containing `ad1a`...maybe someone's over-zealous ad-blocking rule.

Comment: It prints out `https://abs.twimg.com/c/swift/ru/init.faad1a` with `aad1a` marked red. But I don't see anything by `sudo cat /etc/squid/adslist.txt | grep aad1a`

Comment: OK, that  proves it's something in `adslist.txt`.  Now try grepping `adslist.txt` for `aad` or `aad1` or `d1` and other variations. If `aad1a` itself doesn't match anything, that'll be because the actual regexp causing you this problem will have `*` or `?` or other regexp special characters.

Comment: `d1` gave some results, including `.ad1.`. May be this is it? May be it interprets dots not literally, but as wildcards?

Comment: the acl is defined as `url_regex` so yes, they are interpreted as regular expressions.  `.ad1.` looks it is the problem pattern.  comment it out or delete it.

Comment: How to fix? I have many items with dots, which meant not regexps. And why comments are working? Aren't they interpreted as regexps too?

Comment: the entire file is interpreted as a list of regular expressions, dots or no dots (dots are just one of the characters that have special meaning in regexps).  If the squid acl files don't support comments (i don't remember if they do or not), then don't comment out unwanted rules, delete them instead.  the simple answer is: if a particular rule in that file is causing you a problem, then get rid of it.  you now know how to identify those rules.