# How to replace all dots in vi

Tags: vi, replace

How to replace in `vi`? There are numerous explanations in Internet, but most of them doesn't contain information about which buttons to press.

If I enter

```
:s/[.]/[.] <ENTER>
```

then only one occurrence replaced. Pressing `n` does only search.

If I enter

```
:%s/[.]/[.] <ENTER>
```

it replaces dots in entire file, but in first positions only.

For example, it changes `.123pagerank.com` to `[.]123pagerank.com`, ignoring second dot.

How to accomplish?

Comment: If this is in response to my comments in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278337/7696 then you need to understand that **dots are not the problem**.  What you are wanting to do here will replace not only `.` where it should be replaced (i.e. when it should be a literal `.` and not a regexp `.` meaning ANY character), but also those where it **should** mean any character.  i.e. you will break many regexps.  BTW, replacing `.` with `[.]` is the wrong way to do it.  you should replace `.` with `\.` - this is known as `escaping`, it tells the regexp engine to treat the next char as literal.

Comment: you need to gain a much better understanding of regular expressions - what they are, how they work, how to read them, how to write them, how to use them effectively - before you do **anything** except delete the specific rules in your `adslist.txt` file that are causing you a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code for replacing the "dots"

```
:%s/\./_/g <ENTER>
```

Here "_" is replaced word.

This works because Vim uses regex, and to represent a dot `.`, you need to use the backslash `\` before the dot, to search in the file for the dot, because a dot without the backslash means any character, therefore the search will include every character, and it would substitute them with `_`.

Comment: Why is it work?

Comment: Note that the `s/[.]/…` part of the OP’s question works; his big problem was missing the `g` flag.  (Although it’s unclear what he was trying to replace dots *with.*)  Do you have any reason for recommending `\.` rather than `[.]`?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.